# Including files when writing Wordpress admin options page for a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, include

So I've written a couple of classes in separate php files to help me with API calls that I want to make when a user fills in a form on the plugin options page. 
I've also got a config file with some variables I want to include on the options page.
The issue I'm having is that when I require the files, they seem to be including okay because there's no fatal error, but none of the variables or classes are available to use in the function I hook to the action 'admin_menu'.

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'product-dyno/config.php');
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'product-dyno/license.php');
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'product-dyno/member.php');


function product_dyno_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'Product Dyno Options', 'Product Dyno', 
    'manage_options', 'activate-plugin-with-product-dyno', 
    'product_dyno_options' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'product_dyno_plugin_menu' );


function product_dyno_options() {

    $license = new License();

    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Activate plugin '.$PLUGIN_NAME.'</h2>';
    echo '</div>';

    .......
```

$PLUGIN_NAME is required from config.php and I'm getting the error that the variable is undefined.

Strangely, the class does seem to be included because variables used within the constructor of the class which are also included from config.php are also returning as undefined.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the headers already being sent or the order of the wp actions but I really can't work it out and I can't find a similar issue on any forums!

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, $Plugin_name is defined in config.php file, all values define in this file are unavailable in a procedural function.

There's two way to grab data on your function :

- Use global
- use new config() (if the config.php stands in a class)

To use global : at the top of product_dyno_options(), add `global $PLUGIN_NAME;`.

If config.php is in a class, use the same way you use for licence. In the function

```
$config = new config ();
```

Then call it like this where you want after :

```
$config->plugin_name;
```

Hope it helps